# Insertar a .val texto con saltos de linea

Tags: php, javascript, laravel, blade

Soy novato en Laravel y PHP. Tengo que integrar un poco de javascript y me esta dando dolores de cabeza.

Utilizando blade estoy incluyendo campos de la base de datos en ('#anotacion').val

```
$(function() {
            $('#cambioorden').change(function(){
                if($('#cambioorden').val() == '3') {
                    $('#infopresupuesto').show();
                    $('#anotacion').val("--AVISO DE SISTEMA-- \n" +
                        "Diagnóstico y/o presupuesto de su equipo Orden de Trabajo Nº {{$anotacionOt->ot_id}} esta listo: \n" +
                        "" +"\n" +
                        "Diagnóstico: {{$anotacionOt->sintoma}} \n" +
                        "Presupuesto de reparación: $ {{$anotacionOt->presupuesto}} \n" +
                        "Fecha de reparación aproximada: {{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($anotacionOt->fechaentrega)->format('d-m-y') }}  \n" );
                } else {
                    $('#infopresupuesto').hide();

                }
            });
        });
```

El problema se presenta solo en {{$anotacionOt->sintoma}}. Me doy cuenta que cuando el campo tiene varias lineas no funciona (creo porque no me esta incluyendo los \n, blade lo ingresa como texto directamente). Cuando tiene el campo "sintoma" tiene una sola linea funciona perfectamente.

¿Como debería modificarlo?

Desde ya gracias por la ayuda!!

Answer (score 2):

`#anotacion` debe ser un campo que soporte multi-linea, por ejemplo un `<textarea>`. Si `#anotacion` es un input normal (`input type=text` o semejante) no mostrara multiples lineas.

```js
$(function(){
    $("#anotacion1").val("Line1\nLine2\nLine3");
    $("#anotacion2").val("Line1\nLine2\nLine3");
})
```

```css
input, textarea {
  width: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="anotacion1" type=text>

<textarea id="anotacion2" ></textarea>
```

Si el codigo es generado desde un blade template, puedes usar la notacion `{{!! json_encode($variable) !!}}` ([Documentacion en 'Displaying Data'](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#displaying-data))  para escapar los saltos de linea o cualquier caracter especial para un string javascript.

```
"Diagnóstico: " + {{!! json_encode($anotacionOt->sintoma) !!}} + "\n"
```

Ademas, Blade provee un shortcut para este mismo resultado usando @json [(Documentacion en 'Rendering JSON')](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#displaying-data):

```
"Diagnóstico: " + @json($anotacionOt->sintoma) + "\n"
```

Comment: En el ejemplo que pasas veo que pones manualmente los \n (entre Line1 Line2 y Line3) tanto para "anotacion1" como para "anotacion2". Mi campo es textarea pero el texto que quiero incluir usando blade de la base de datos- campo sintoma  no cuenta con esos \n.

Comment: te entiendo, en ese caso debes usar una funcion para transformar el texto en un string para javascript (por ejemplo, json_encode). Agregaré ejemplos para eso

Comment: Excelente F.Igor! Muchas gracias! Gracias a tu ayuda termine solucionandolo. Por si algun otro tiene el problema. Termine usando "Diagnóstico: " + @json($anotacionOt->sintoma) + "\n" +